# Values of local and global variable values in C

Tags: c, global-variables, local-variables

I don't seem to understand what's happening here

```
#include <stdio.h>

int var = 5;

int main(){
    int var = var;
    printf("%d",var);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this program print a garbage value when the value of var is assigned to be 5?

Comment: Scope........................

Comment: The inner `var` shadows the outer one. You're not assigning 5 to anything in `main()`.

Comment: The local `int var` exists already before the initialization. So it does not use the global `int var` for that.

Comment: Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the local var has priority on the global var.
So the compiler translate it as (local) var = (local) var